# How to remove /n from the end of a string that is printed from a dictionary?

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary, printing, newline

I have a dictionary that contains multiple variables. The variables are defined by looking through a file and randomly selecting one of the lines. When I print the dictionary the strings have "\n" at the end.

```
import random as r
import math
FNameF = open("First-Names.txt")
LNameF = open("Last-Names.txt")
lines = FNameF.readlines()
lines2 = LNameF.readlines()
Name = (lines[r.randint(1,200) - 1])
LName = (lines2[r.randint(1,300) - 1])
Age = math.floor(abs(r.random() - r.random()) * (1 + 85 - 16) + 16)
people = {"person1" : {'Name': Name, 'Last Name': LName, 'Age': Age}
}
print(people["person1"])
```

The output is:
{'Name': 'Wilson\n', 'Last Name': 'Terrell\n', 'Age': 61}
What I want is:
{'Name': 'Wilson', 'Last Name': 'Terrell', 'Age': 61} ,
removing the "\n"

Comment: Could you please include the code that defines or assigns LName and Age?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
FNameF = open("First-Names.txt")
allLines = FNameF.read()
lines = allLines.split('\n')
Name = (lines[r.randint(1,200) - 1])
people = {"person1" : {'Name': Name, 'Last Name': LName, 'Age': Age}
}
print(people["person1"])
```